# It's a car of my father's friend's

Tags: possessives, double-possessives

I read that we really could use the double possession like

> It's a car of my father's

But somewhy we can't say:

> It's a car of my father's friend's

Like, the triple possession? Is it true or we actually can avail of it, too?

Comment: Incidentally, *somewhy* is not a standard English word. Instead, say *for some reason*.

Comment: It's incorrect?

Comment: *Somehow*, *somewhat*, and *somewhere* are words. You cannot combine the word *some* with other interrogative words (*who*, *when*, *which*, *why*).

Comment: Thne what to exchange "somewhen" with?

Comment: "Somewhen" should be replaced with "whenever" or "sometime" depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

You can use as many possessives in a row as you want.

For instance, this is perfectly *grammatical*:

> It's a car of my father's friend's daughter's boyfriend's employer's wife's.

But while it's grammatical, it can become difficult to follow at a certain point.

In the case of your original sentence, it's short enough to be easily understandable—and there's no reason why you can't say it.

---

But you may be thinking of this construction instead:

> It's a car that belongs to my father's friend.

In this case, the final noun doesn't use an apostrophe. The same would be true at only a single level of possession:

> It's a car that belongs to my father.

Comment: "It's a car of my father's friend's daughter's boyfriend's employer's wife's."
Weeeeeeeeeeeeell, I am not going to sleep

Comment: Related: https://youtu.be/CZd_YyFzPD0